# example of compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E=l^p=\left\{x=\left(x_n\right): x_n\in\mathbb{R}, \sum_{1}^{\infty}\left|x_n\right|^p<\infty\right\}$ with $1\le p<\infty$, $\left\|x\right\|_E=\left(\sum_{1}^{\infty}\left|x_n\right|^p\right)^{1/p}.$ Let $\left(\lambda_n\right)$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and consider the operator $T$ defined by
$$T(x)=\left(\lambda_1x_x,\ldots,\lambda_nx_n,\ldots\right)$$
where $x\in l^p$.
Prove that $T$ is a compact operator from $E$ to $E$ iff $\lambda_n\rightarrow 0$.

Can anyone give me some hints to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe show it is an SOT limit of finite rank operators.

Comment: What finite rank operators should I use ?

Comment: Your finite rank operators should be like finite versions of your operator. What would this correspond to in your case?

Comment: I think $T_k(x)=(\lambda_1x_1,\ldots,\lambda_kx_k,0\ldots,0,\ldots)$. Is it right ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for.

Comment: Thank you! I finished the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hint for $\implies$: If $\lambda_n \not \to 0,$ then for some $\epsilon>0,|\lambda_{n_k}| > \epsilon$ along a subsequence $n_k.$ Letting $e_n$ denote the usual "basis" vector, consider the sequence $e_{n_k}$ in the unit ball of $l^p$ and its images under $T.$

Comment: If there is a sub-sequence of $T(e_{n_k})$ that tend to $u\in l^p$, then $u$ must be equal to zero. However, $||T(e_{n_k})||=\lambda_{n_k}>\epsilon$, so there is no sub-sequence of $T(e_{n_k})$ that  tends to zero. Is it what you mean ?

Comment: I was thinking $T(e_{n_k})$ has no Cauchy subsequence.

Comment: Ok! I understood your goal.